# TO_DATE function

Tags: sql, amazon-redshift

I try following select statment:

```
SELECT  coalesce(rewards_Created_Activated_Failed.membership_id, expired.membership_id) AS MembershipID
   ,coalesce(date_sub(to_date(expired.occurred_at), 'YYY-MM-DD')
                    ,to_date((max_expiredDate.expiry_date), 'YYY-MM-DD')
                    ,to_date(rewards_Created_Activated_Failed.expiry_date), 'YYY-MM-DD') AS DateMembershipExpires

FROM (
    SELECT *,
                row_number() over (PARTITION BY membership_id ORDER BY status_change_date_time asc) AS RowNum
    FROM model.movie_membership_status
            WHERE event_name in ('MembershipCreatedEvent', 'MemberShipActivatedEvent')

 ) AS rewards_Created_Activated_Failed


LEFT JOIN
(
    SELECT membership_id
          ,max(status_change_date_time) as occurred_at
    FROM model.movie_membership_status
    WHERE event_name = 'MembershipExpiredEvent'
        GROUP BY membership_id
) expired

ON expired.membership_id = rewards_Created_Activated_Failed.membership_id
```

But I get the following error:

> ERROR: 42883: function to_date(timestamp without time zone) does not exist

How to fix that error?

Comment: Calling `to_date()` on a value that is already a date or timestamp makes no sense whatsoever. It's intended to convert a varchar _into_ a date, not the other way round. If you want to format the output use `to_char()`

Comment: Probably irrelevant, but - what kind of a date format is it, '**YYY**-MM-DD'? 3 digits for a year?

Answer (score 0):

```
test=> \df to_date
                           List of functions
   Schema   |  Name   | Result data type | Argument data types |  Type  
------------+---------+------------------+---------------------+--------
 pg_catalog | to_date | date             | text, text          | normal
(1 row)
```

You'll have to supply the desired format as second argument.

See [the documentation](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/functions-formatting.html).

Answer (score 0):

It looks like `expired.occurred_at`, `max_expiredDate.expiry_date`, and `rewards_Created_Activated_Failed.expiry_date` are already dates. That means you don't need to call `to_date` on them. In addition, there is no `date_sub` function in redshift. I'm not sure what you're trying to do there, but maybe look at [DATEDIFF](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_DATEDIFF_function.html)?

You probably want something like this (ordered to match your previous coalesce statement):

```
coalesce(
  rewards_Created_Activated_Failed.expiry_date,
  expired.occurred_at,
  max_expiredDate.expiry_date
) AS DateMembershipExpires
```